# I don't have eth0 but eth1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-adapter, udev

How come I don't have `eth0` but an `eth1` instead?

I restart service `udev`, like below, but my ether card is still `eth1`, not `eth0`

```
% service udev --full-restart
* Stopping the hotplug events dispatcher udevd                          [ OK ]
```

Need help.

PS my system is Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy x86_64

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this should be moved to AskUbuntu?

Comment: You didn't really ask a question. What help do you need?

Comment: First thing that springs to mind is that you cloned the box. or changed devices. In that case remove the persistent-rules file from /etc/udev/rules.d (I don't know what number it is in your distro).

Comment: I'm curious to what exactly its breaking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my Kubuntu system, the assignment of the name to the ethernet NIC is made through the following rule: go to /etc/udev/rules.d, issue the following command

```
  grep eth0 *
```

whose output is

```
  70-persistent-net.rules:SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="e8:e0:b7:be:72:6a", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

The part *70-persistent-net.rules* identifies the file in which the word *eth0* is contained, the remaining part is the actual line containing *eth0*.

The fact that there is just one line makes it very simple to modify it.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that'd do it. Now, I'm wondering how the file ends up there at the first place. I.e., if I remove it, would it get re-generated again? Oh, found it -- the file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules